# Kendo UI custom validation not working with template and viewmodel

Tags: javascript, validation, kendo-ui

I have a form template, which is bound to a view-model. All the strings (labels and validation messages) are set in the view model.

Form fields also has validations and so far, simple validations work fine. However, I also want to add a custom validation rule. Issue is, the custom validation rule never gets hit when `validate` method is called.

Here is the code:

```
<div data-template="div-template" data-bind="source: this" id="mytemplate">
    <script id="div-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <div>
                <form id="ui_test_form" data-role="validator" novalidate="novalidate">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="lbl_salary" class="label-caption">#=strings.salary#</label>
                        <input id="salary" name="Salary" type="number" value="" min="1" data-type="number" required validationMessage="#=strings.salaryRequired#" style="margin-right: 35px; "/>
                        <span data-for='salary' class='k-invalid-msg'></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="lbl_startdate" class="label-caption">#=strings.startDate#</label>
                        <input type="text" id="StartDate" data-role='datepicker' name="StartDate" data-type="date" required validationMessage="#=strings.startDateRequired#" />
                        <span data-for='StartDate' class='k-invalid-msg'></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="lbl_enddate" class="label-caption">#=strings.endDate#</label>
                        <input type="text" id="EndDate" data-role='datepicker' name="EndDate" data-type="date" required validationMessage="#=strings.endDateRequired#" data-enddate-msg="End date should be after start date" />
                        <span data-for='EndDate' class='k-invalid-msg'></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="label-caption"></label>
                        <button class="k-button col-md-6" type="button" value="Submit" data-bind="click: save">#=strings.validate#</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
<script>
  $(function () {

    var strings = {
      salary: "Salary",
      startDate: "Start Date",
      endDate: "End Date",
      endDateInvalid: " End Date should be after start date",
      salaryRequired: " Salary is required",
      startDateRequired: " Start Date is required",
      endDateRequired: " End Date is required",
      validate: "Validate"
    };

   var formViewModel = kendo.observable({
     strings: strings,
     save: function(){

       var validator = $("#ui_test_form").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
       if(validator.validate()){
         debugger;
       }else{
         debugger;
       }

     }
   });

   kendo.bind($("#mytemplate"), formViewModel);

   function initializeComponents(){
     $("#salary").kendoNumericTextBox({ format: 'c' });

     var container = $("#mytemplate");
     container.kendoValidator({
       rules: {
         greaterdate: function (input) {
           //I want to compare start and end date here, this function never gets called
           debugger;
         }
       }
     });
   }

   initializeComponents();
 });
</script>
```

Here is the working example in [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ekoKu/2)

Any thoughts/suggestions on this?

Comment: i would suggest moving the validation that you have (using the 'required' and such) from the html and placing them in your javascript validator. They might be interfering with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that in Dojo; however, it doesn't work.

Comment: i just ran your Dojo example and the custom validation rule is being hit..

Comment: Do you mean this method `greaterdate: function (input)` is being hit? I'm sorry, it never does.

Comment: Yes it is being hit. Is your F12 Developer Tools on Chrome open when you're running this in Dojo? Because for the `debugger` to trigger it must be open. Also you have to change an input and click outside the input and i assure you it will hit

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was never changing any inputs and was expecting custom validation to be hit. Thanks for the clarification. If you convert that to an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: will do, glad i could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being hit. Is your F12 Developer Tools on Chrome open when you're running this in Dojo? Because for the debugger to trigger it must be open. Also you have to change an input and click outside the input and i assure you it will hit. Try this [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ekoKu/9)

Comment: Well yes, my developer tools were open. However, I missed the "change the input part". Thanks again for your help.